# Matplotlib process keep outputing figures without script execution

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pytest, background-process

I am facing the problem of having a matplotlib figure that shows up from a python script that was run previously. I mean that the script is no longer running, but I still have the figure showing up "randomly". It might be each time I run a different python script that saves a matplotlib figure but not totally sure.

Details:

- The scripts were executed from a vscode integrated terminal.
- I can see the processus on my gpu or using `top` command when the figure shows up, but I soon as I close the figure window the processus disapears and will re appear later.

Code snippet:

```
from pytorch_grad_cam import GradCAM
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.model_targets import ClassifierOutputTarget
from pytorch_grad_cam.utils.image import show_cam_on_image
from torchvision.models import resnet50
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = resnet50(pretrained=True)
target_layers = [model.layer4[-1]]
# load an image an put it in a pytorch tensor
input_tensor = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
# Create an input tensor image for your model..
# Note: input_tensor can be a batch tensor with several images!

# Construct the CAM object once, and then re-use it on many images:
cam = GradCAM(model=model, target_layers=target_layers, use_cuda=True)

targets = [ClassifierOutputTarget(281)]

# You can also pass aug_smooth=True and eigen_smooth=True, to apply smoothing.
grayscale_cam = cam(input_tensor=input_tensor, targets=targets)

# In this example grayscale_cam has only one image in the batch:
grayscale_cam = grayscale_cam[0, :]
rgb_img = input_tensor[0, :].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()
visualisation = show_cam_on_image(rgb_img, grayscale_cam, use_rgb=True)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(visualisation)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python: 3.9.16

What I have tried so far:

- Killing the processes when it shows up
- Rebooting pc
- uninstall and reinstall matplotlib in my virtual environmment
- Looking at the parent process using `pstree` and killing it.
- Re running the script and adding `plt.clf()`.

It might be linked to an attempt to use `plt.ion()` in the problematic script. Or the opencv library that is used in background of the pytorch_grad_cam package from [here](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam).

*Update:*
*- It seems that what triggers the figures is saving a file in my vscode editor...*

- In pstree prompt the python process linked to the matplotlib figure has a code (i.e. vscode) parent process

Comment: How are you saving the file, exactly?  If you're saving with F5, that would do it, or if you have redefined the Ctrl-S shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script was triggered because of the file name starting with test_* and the loaded python environment containing pytest package. I didn't know that pytest was triggered by saving a modified file when the vs code python extension was enabled.